# vb script browse and capture file path

Tags: vbscript, hta

Hi I am using following vb-script to browse for file and capture its path for further processing.

```
  Dim sStartPath, sStartFile, sFilter, sCaption
  sStartPath = "D:\Remote"
  sStartFile = sStartPath & "\nul"
  sFilter    = "All Files (*.*)|*.*|" _
      & "VBScript (*.vbs;*.vbc)|*.vbs;*.vbc|" _
      & "HTML (*.htm;*.html;*.hta)|*.htm;*.html;*.hta|"
  sCaption = "Choose a File:"


Sub BrForFile_onclick
    sBFF = Dlg.OpenFileDlg( CStr(sStartFile), , CStr(sFilter), CStr(sCaption))
    If not sBFF = "" Then 
      document.Copy_To_PC.txtfile.value = sBFF
      document.Copy_To_PC.OKbuton.value = "Treat file"
    End If
  ProcessFile sBff.path
End Sub
```

I can not get path using `sBFF.path`. What is wrong with this. I have to process .txt, .sql and .xml files using my vbscript.

My `ProcessFile` sub takes file path and process it. Initially I was hardfeeding file path to the Sub

Comment: Seems it should be `ProcessFile sBff` instead of `ProcessFile sBff.path`, since you are assigning a string value to `sBFF` variable, but not an object.

Comment: such a silly mistake......... I think I am High on Friday Night...... ;-)